# Should I set values using the return or by giving a reference?

Tags: c++, memory

Suppose I have a mouse position watcher, which should let the user extract the mouse position.  Should the mouse position be set in the method and returned:

```
Mouse_Position Mouse_Watcher::get_mouse_position( void ) const
{
   Mouse_Position return_val = Mouse_Position( this->mp );

   // memory stuff so the value can escape this scope and not cause segmentation faults

   return return_val;
}

Mouse_Position mp = Mouse_Position();
mp = mouse_man::get_mouse_position();
```

or the slightly easier way I've found:

```
void Mouse_Watcher::sync_mouse_position( Mouse_Position & destination ) const
{
   // the class handles copying
   // if the stuff is primitive and uses this syncing method,
   //   seems like a ton of avoided memory mishaps
   destination.sync_x( this->mp );
   destination.sync_y( this->mp );
}

Mouse_Position mp = Mouse_Position();
mouse_man::sync_mouse_position( mp );

// at this point mp has position values
```

I've been used to setting values using the return, but I don't like unnecessarily including memory management if I can help it.  Should I go back to using returns to keep up with standards?

Comment: I hope you have a better motivation than "keeping up with standards."  There *is* a better reason; code that's written in a more *functional* style tends to be better behaved, generally, and is easier to reason about.

Comment: I wonder about how to interpret functional; because functions generate an output( so I should use returns ).

Functions can also transform their input, no?  So you feed it something, and that that something might pop up different than when it entered( which is that syncing method ).

Comment: How is the second form easier in any way?  Note that the first form can be used in a simpler way: `auto mp = mouse_man::get_mouse_position();`  There is no need to assign a default-constructed `Mouse_Position` to the variable beforehand.

Comment: @5gon12eder Don't I still have to code get_mouse_position() to handle how that Mouse_Position object gets out of the scope of the function?  If I give the function a Mouse_Position object outside the scope of the function, I won't have to worry about managing it's memory from the function.

Comment: In general, the idea in functional programming is to avoid side-effects. Changing the input parameter is a side-effect.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ahhh, ok, I was wondering what the side effect was if the purpose of the function was to cause that change.  But I see that the return value of a function should really be its only way to provide output.

Comment: "I don't like unnecessarily including memory management if I can help it" - If returning a MousePosition by value involves any memory management on the side of its user, the class insufficiently encapsulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, this depends on the purpose of the function and the nature of the type it's retrieving/extracting. But it's usually easy to make a choice based on the properties of the type.

**1) The value is a primitive such as `int` or `char`**

Then the choice is effectively between:

```
int x = getInt();
```

and

```
int x;
setInt(x);
```

I would strongly prefer returning the value, because:

- It just looks more natural/normal/intuitive/readable/etc.
- Now that the function takes an argument, it's *possible* that its behavior depends on the current value of that argument. Semantically, the current value of x is completely irrelevant to what this function does, so why give the function access to it?
- Copying and assigning `int`s costs basically nothing. Odds are both versions get optimized to the same instructions anyway.

**2) The value is a "trivial" struct/class (eg, no private data, methods or memory management)**

I assume your Mouse_Position class falls into this category. This case is basically identical to #1, because a class like this behaves much the same as a primitive.

More formally, when I say this class is like a primitive value, I'm saying this class has "value semantics". That means a lot of things, such as if two objects of that class have the same data members, they are completely interchangeable for all intents and purposes. This is a very nice property to have when it comes to reasoning about your code.

**3) The value has methods/private data/memory management, but it implements RAII and still technically has value semantics**

This is where STL container classes go. A std::vector definitely contains private data, including a pointer to memory it has to manually manage, but its constructors, destructors and copy operations are implemented in such a way that it still behaves like a primitive value in many ways. In particular, two vectors that compare equal are still interchangeable; it doesn't matter what region of memory they happen to be storing their values in.

In this case, whether you return by value or take a reference parameter mostly comes down to efficiency. In C++ you normally don't want to *copy* classes like this if you don't have to, because that implies copying all the private data or memory being managed (which may involve allocating more memory). However, move semantics in modern C++ make it so that returning a std::vector does not necessarily perform a copy anymore, so simply returning it by value is becoming more acceptable (I won't try to explain the exact conditions under which copies do/don't happen before/after C++11; that's too complicated).

**4) The value has no trace of value semantics, and preserving its identity is important**

These are typically classes that represent external dependencies like files, databases, network connections, peripheral devices, rendering contexts and so on. It often does not make sense to copy these objects (you can't give your computer more keyboards by copying a `Keyboard` class) so functions operating on them basically have to operate on pointers/references to them as a simple matter of correctness. Obviously here the decision is made for you.

---

Short answer: Don't use pointers/references when they're completely unnecessary. Simply copying/returning values often results in more intuitive and much better-behaved code.

Comment: Primitive like and value semantics are almost never used interchangeably. Most classes in c++ have value semantics, that's what you should expect. A class that doesn't have value semantics should almost always have a deleted copy construction/assignment. I think the word you are looking for is trivial.

Comment: Even before the appearance of move semantics in c++11, RVO pretty well guaranteed that returning by value was fine.

Your 4) is conflating several issues: value semantics, copyability, singletons, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of cases, you should prefer to actually return things from functions. Passing in a non-const reference to hold the state of your value is typically referred to as an out parameter, or an in-out parameter if you are both using its existing state, and then modifying it.

There are a couple of disadvantages of non-const reference parameters:

1) It looks awkward, and is less clear. You don't know whether it's an out parameter or an in/out parameter without documentation. Maybe it's a normal parameter but someone forgot `const`.

2) You have to construct a value yourself, and then pass it in. Contrast this with returning the value, your first example is better written as

```
Mouse_Position mp = mouse_man::get_mouse_position();
```

I never create a pointless object, and reduce noise in my code.

There are only a couple of reasons I would ever consider using the pattern you are suggesting; I will list them from least to most technical.

1) The object is actually an in/out parameter. This means that you want to use the existing state of the object. In/out parameters themselves are often better avoided, but sometimes they are a good choice. This is not the case here.

2) The object you need to return is neither copyable nor movable (or you are using c++03, and it's not copyable, but I'll disregard that). This is exceedingly rare.

3) Performance reasons. This is a pretty involved issue. The general rule of thumb here is that the compiler is smarter than you think. For instance, if your data type is large, you might argue that returning from a function involves a copy, which is expensive, whereas passing in a reference and modifying it in place might be somehow cheaper. In practice, due to wonderful things like the Return Value Optimization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) this cost is elided in most situations. I could talk a lot more about this, but it's a complicated topic and it doesn't really seem to be relevant here.

In short, with the vast majority of types, and without extreme performance considerations, you should just return the type by value, unless you actually care about its prior state.